# JTA how to do not rollback anything?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jta

I want to rollback my transaction on an exception which works absolutely fine. But now I do not want to rollback all actions I made.
For example, a request to my application gets processed and several database actions on multiple databases are done. If the exception is thrown I want to rollback all actions on one of my databases and only 2 actions on the second database. How can I do that? I always end up rolling bback the whole transaction...

what I tried so far:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public <Param> GenericResponseMsg executeRequest (Param myParam) {
     entityManager1.persist(someEntity); // rollback
     ...
}

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void addFailedRequestToDatabase() {
     entityManager2.persist(otherEntity); // do not rollback
     ...
}
```

I also tried to annotate the class with

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

but this results in the following exception:

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Connection can not be used while enlisted in another transaction
Error Code: 0
```

Any ideas? I am somehow stuck and don't know what to do anymore...

**EDIT:**
Here is the workflow you asked for:

```
@Stateless
@Path("my/path") 
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class MyRessource {

    @EJB
    private MyEJB myEjb;

    @POST
    @Path("method/Path")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public GenericResponseMsg doSomeStuff(Param param) throws Exception {
        try {
            return myEjb.executeRequest(param);
        } catch(Throwable throwable) {
            myEjb.addFailedRequestToDatabase();
            throw throwable;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The test with REQUIRES_NEW should work, if you invoke the method correctly. How did that test look in a more complete flow? How and where were all the methods called?

Comment: It seems that this is an issue with openejb. I tried my code directly on my wildfly server and it works as expected. The error only occurs with openejb

Answer (score 0):

@TransactionAttribute is support for EJB as per the specification. @Transactional support is coming in tomee 7 (currently under vote @asf).

Side note: tomee and openejb standalone code is 100% the same for JTA support.